# Return keyword in functions C#

Tags: c#

I have an easy question concerning C# function output or return.
I have tried to understand and then looked in internet but no answer!
can you please explain to me what does a function with multiple `return` statements do.  For example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using lj;

namespace ljack
{

public class joystick : MonoBehaviour {

public static float a;      
public static float b;


void Start(){


      int[] idList = GetAllLabJacks();      

 if (idList.Length == 0)
                Debug.Log("No LabJacks found!");
            else
            {
                // List the IDs of LabJacks we found
                foreach (int id in idList)
                {
                   Debug.Log("id=" + id);



                }
            }           

        }       


void Update(){


 // Read in the analog input from channel 0
            // and output the result


            int ljID = 2;
            int overVoltage = 0;
            float voltage1 = 0.0f;

            int result = LabJack.EAnalogIn(ref ljID, 0, 0, 0, ref overVoltage, ref voltage1);

              //Debug.Log("voltage1="+ voltage1);


            float voltage2=0.0f;
             result = LabJack.EAnalogIn(ref ljID, 0, 1, 0, ref overVoltage, ref voltage2);

            //Debug.Log("voltage2="+ voltage2);



            a=voltage1;
            b=voltage2;




}

 // This returns an array of all the local IDs which we use.
        //
public static int[] GetAllLabJacks()
        {
            // Make sure we allocate space for what is passed
            int[] productIDList = new int[127];
            int[] serialNumList = new int[127];
            int[] localIDList = new int[127];
            int[] powerList = new int[127];
            int[,] calMatrix = new int[127, 20];
            int numFound = 0;
            int reserved1 = 0, reserved2 = 0;

            // Call the ListAll function.  We must use the keyword ref for parameters 
            // that aren't arrays that return data
            int result = LabJack.ListAll(productIDList, serialNumList, localIDList,
                powerList, calMatrix, ref numFound, ref reserved1, ref reserved2);



            int[] ljs = new int[numFound];
            int i = 0;

            // count how many we found and set
            // the array which will be returned
            // to contain valid IDs
            foreach (int id in localIDList)
            {
                if (id != 9999)
                {
                    ljs[i] = id;
                    ++i;
                }
            }

            // return that array
            return ljs;
        }       

 // This is our function that read's analog input
public static float Getjoyst(){


            return a;
            return b;
        }            

}
}
```

will it return a or b, or one after another?

```
look for this code also

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


public class menu : MonoBehaviour {


// name .. of the player

public  string nom;   
public  string pathologie;
public  string comment;


// v is used to display the value of( niveau de vitesses)

public static int v;        


//pour pouvoir copier les donnees dans le script mouvement, tracction et central

public static string playnom;
public static string playpathologie;
public static string playcomment;   
public static string envir; 
public static string main;  
public static bool Activer;
public static bool Desactiver;  


// le type du fauteuil  

public static bool Propultion;  
public static bool Central;
public static bool Traction;


// obstacles

public static bool  Serie1; 
public static bool  Serie2;
public static bool  Serie1et2;


//coté de commande

public static bool aucun;
public static bool gauche;


//env

public static bool droite;  
public bool exterieur;
public bool cerah;
public bool nan;
public bool crnf;


// mouvement des obstacles

public  bool activer;
public  bool desactiver;


// used to display the text

public  GUIText fauteuil; // used to display the text fauteuil
public GUIText vitesse;  // used to display the text vitesse
public GUIText obstacles; // used to display the text obstacles
public GUIText mouv;    // used to display the text obstacles en mouvement
public GUIText env;    // used to display the text Envirennement

public GUIText info;    
public GUIText cotecommande;


// pour les indications et les affichage

public GUIText indication;
public GUIText indication1; 
public GUIText indication2; 
public GUIText niveau;   //used to display the text niveau
public GUIText important;   


//importation des variables

public bool etat1; // pour importer des variables bool de mouvement
public bool pro;    
public bool etat2; // pour importer des variables bool de central
public bool cen;    
public bool etat3;// pour importer des variables bool de traction
public bool tra;    


public string information1; // pour importer des variables de type string de mouvement
public string information2; // pour improter des variables de type string de central    
public string information3; // pour importer des variables de type string de traction           





void OnGUI(){


//  premiers bouton du menu principal

    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,50,200,25),"Information utilisateur")){

            main="Information utilisateur";

        }


    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10,100,200,25),"Fauteuil")) {

            main="Fauteuil";
        }


    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,150,200,25),"Environnement")){

            main="Envirennement";
        }   

    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,200,200,25),"Raccourcis clavier")){

            main="Raccourcis clavier";

        }


    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,250,200,25),"Commencer la simulation")){

            main="Commancer la sim";

        }


    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(10,300,200,25),"Quitter")){

            main="Quitter";
            Application.Quit();

        }       


//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 


if (main=="Information utilisateur"){

            // si le buttoninfo utili est appuyé

            GUI.Label(new Rect(300,100,100,30),"Nom: ");  //On ecrit sur un label le mot nom
            nom=GUI.TextField(new Rect(350,100,200,30), nom); //reservation d'une case rectangulaire pour l'ecriture d'une chaine de caractères 


            GUI.Label(new Rect(300,150,100,30),"pathologie: ");
            pathologie=GUI.TextField(new Rect(370,150,200,30), pathologie);


            GUI.Label(new Rect(300,200,100,30),"Commentaires: ");
            comment=GUI.TextField(new Rect(300,250,300,100), comment);


            info.text="Informations utilisateur";

            indication2.text="Renseignez les informations puis appuyez sur OK";


            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(300,400,100,25),"ok")){

                if (nom==""||pathologie==""){

                    important.text="nom est pathologie obligatoires ";

                }

                else
                    {   
                        playnom=nom;
                        playpathologie=pathologie;
                        playcomment=comment;

                        main="";
                        important.text="";

                }
            }           

}       



            else{

                info.text="";
                indication2.text="";

            }




//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------     

if(main=="Fauteuil"){ 

// si le boutton fauteuil allors

//affichage des textes  

        fauteuil.text=main;
        vitesse.text="vitesse Du Fauteuil"; 
        indication.text="Choisissez la configuration du fauteil puis appuyez sur OK";
        cotecommande.text="cote de commande";   


        //criation des bouttons

        if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(300,100,150,25),Propultion,"Propultion")){

                Propultion=true;
                Central=false;
                Traction=false;

            }


        if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(450,100,150,25),Central,"Central")){

                Propultion=false;
                Central=true;
                Traction=false;


            }

        if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(600,100,150,25),Traction,"Traction")){

                Propultion=false;
                Central=false;
                Traction=true;

            }


        if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(300,300,150,25),gauche,"gauche ")){

                gauche=true;
                droite=false;

            }       


        if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(450,300,150,25),droite,"droite")){

                gauche=false;
                droite=true;

            }


        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(300,400,100,25),"ok")){

                main="";

            }


//si le buton + alors on augmente le niveau     

        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(300,200,25,25),"-")){

        v=v-1;

        }


// si le bouton - alors on deminue le niveau    

        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(450,200,25,25),"+")) {

        v=v+1;

        }

        niveau.text="niveau "+v;

}   


else{ 

        // effacer les texte si le bouton fauteil n'est pa appuyé

        fauteuil.text="";
        vitesse.text="";    
        niveau.text=""; 
        indication.text=""; 
        cotecommande.text="";

}   


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if (main=="Envirennement"){ 

// si le button envirennement alors

            aucun=true;
            desactiver=true;
            obstacles.text="Obstacles";
            indication1.text="Choisissez les obstacles et l'envirennement puis appuyez sur OK";
            env.text="Envirennement";

//les obstacles

             if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(300,100,150,25),Serie1,"Serie 1(cones)")){

                Serie1=true;
                Serie2=false;
                Serie1et2=false;
                aucun=false;
                mouv.text="";   
                desactiver=true;
                activer=false;

            }


            if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(450,100,150,25),Serie2,"Serie 2")){

                Serie1=false;
                Serie2=true;
                Serie1et2=false;
                aucun=false;
                mouv.text="Obstacles en mouvement"; 

                //mouvement des obstacles

                if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(300,200,100,25),activer,"Activer")){

                activer=true;
                desactiver=false;

                }

                if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(450,200,100,25),desactiver,"Desactiver")){

                desactiver=true;
                activer=false;

                }           

            }   


            if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(600,100,150,25),Serie1et2,"Serie 1 et 2")){

                Serie1=false;
                Serie2=false;
                Serie1et2=true;
                aucun=false;
                mouv.text="Obstacles en mouvement"; 

                //mouvement des obstacles

                if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(300,200,100,25),activer,"Activer")){

                activer=true;
                desactiver=false;

                }

                if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(450,200,100,25),desactiver,"Desactiver")){

                desactiver=true;
                activer=false;

                }   

            }


            if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(750,100,150,25),aucun,"Aucun obstacle")){

                Serie1=false;
                Serie2=false;
                Serie1et2=false;
                aucun=true;
                desactiver=true;
                activer=false;
                mouv.text="";

            }


//envirennement 


            if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(300,300,100,25),exterieur,"Exterieur")){

            exterieur=true;
            cerah=false;
            nan=false;
            crnf=false; 

            }

            if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(450,300,100,25),cerah,"CERAH")){

            exterieur=false;
            nan=false;
            cerah=true;
            crnf=false;

            }   

            if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(600,300,100,25),nan,"NANCY")){

            exterieur=false;
            cerah=false;
            nan=true;
            crnf=false;

            }

            if(GUI.Toggle(new Rect(750,300,100,25),crnf, "CRNF")){
            exterieur=false;
            cerah=false;
            nan=false;
            crnf=true;  

            }


            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(300,400,100,25),"ok")){

                mouv.text="";
                main="";
                Activer=activer;
                Desactiver=desactiver;

            }


}       


else{

obstacles.text="";
indication1.text="";
env.text="";

} 

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      


if(main=="Commancer la sim"){

            if (nom==""||pathologie==""){

                important.text="nom et pathologie obligatoires ";
            }

            else

            {

                if (cerah){

                Application.LoadLevel("scene1");
                envir="CERAH";

                }   



                if (exterieur){

                Application.LoadLevel("scene2");
                envir="exterieur";

                }   



                if (nan){

                Application.LoadLevel("scene5");
                envir="NANCY";

                }       

                if(crnf){

                Application.LoadLevel("scene4");
                envir="CRNF";   

                }

            }

}


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       

if(main=="Raccourcis clavier"){

        GUI.Label(new Rect(300,50,600,25),"Z  E  R  T  Y  U: Changer la position de la camera  ");  


        GUI.Label(new Rect(300,75,500,25),"C  V  N  B : type d'obstacles .  "); 
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,100,500,25),"C : Serie 1 et 2 .");   
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,125,500,25),"V:  Serie 2 (humain).");    
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,150,500,25),"N:  Serie 1 (cones)."); 
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,175,500,25),"B: Aucun obstacle.");   


        GUI.Label(new Rect(300,200,500,30),"A  D: Activer ou desactiver le mouvement des obstacles serie2. ");      
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,225,500,25),"A: Activer.  ");    
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,250,500,25),"D: Desactiver. ");  


        GUI.Label(new Rect(300,275,500,25),"1  2  3  4  5: Les niveaux de vitesses.   ");   
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,300,500,25),"1: 02 KM/H. ");     
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,325,500,25),"2: 04 KM/H. "); 
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,350,500,25),"3: 06 KM/H. "); 
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,375,500,25),"4: 08 KM/H. "); 
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,400,500,25),"5: 10 KM/H.");      


        GUI.Label(new Rect(300,425,500,25),"S  Q:Enregistrement des donnees dans un fichier texte. ");  
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,450,500,25),"S: Commencer ou Reprendre l'enregistrement ");  
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,475,500,25),"Q: Arret de l'enregistrement. ");   


        GUI.Label(new Rect(300,500,500,25),"F  O : Ouverture et fermeture des portes de l'ascenseur de l'envenimement C.R.N.F. ");      
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,525,500,25),"O: Ouverture des portes de l'ascenseur. "); 
            GUI.Label(new Rect(350,550,500,25),"F: Fermetures des portes de l'ascenseur. ");    


        GUI.Label(new Rect(300,575,1450,25),"P: Pause et Retour au menu principal");    



}       


}   


void Start()

{

        // importation des variables

        etat1=mouvement.typefaut();
        pro=mouvement.PROPULTION;

        etat2=central.typefaut();
        cen=central.CENTRAL;

        etat3=traction.typefaut();
        tra=traction.TRACTION;


        if(pro){

        information1=mouvement.utilis();
        nom=mouvement.NOM;  
        pathologie=mouvement.PATHOLOGIE;
        comment=mouvement.COMMENT;  

        }


        if(cen){

        information2=central.utilis();
        nom=central.NOM;    
        pathologie=central.PATHOLOGIE;
        comment=central.COMMENT;        

        }


        if(tra){

        information3=traction.utilis();
        nom=traction.NOM;   
        pathologie=traction.PATHOLOGIE;
        comment=traction.COMMENT;   

        }


                playnom=nom;
                playpathologie=pathologie;
                playcomment=comment;


        // choix par defaut

                Propultion=true;
                Central=false;
                Traction=false;
                gauche=false;
                droite=true;
                v=3;
                Serie1=false;
                Serie2=false;
                Serie1et2=false;
                aucun=true;
                desactiver=false;
                activer=true;

}   


void Update ()

    {

//limiter les niveau entre 1 et 10      

        if (v>=5){
            v=5;
        }

        if(v<=1){
            v=1;
        }


// for saving the data in txt file

        playnom=nom;
        playpathologie=pathologie;
        playcomment=comment;    
        Time.timeScale=0; // temps en arret

}


public  static string Getnom(){  

//pour la recuperation des données de type string dans le script mouvement

        return playnom;
        return playpathologie;
        return playcomment; 
        return envir;
        return main;

}


public static bool Getetat(){   

//pour la recuperation des données de type bool dans le script mouvement

        return  Activer;
        return  Desactiver;
        return  Serie1;
        return  Serie2;
        return  Serie1et2;
        return  aucun;
        return  Propultion;
        return  Central;
        return  Traction;
        return  gauche;
        return droite;

}


public static int Getvit(){

        return v;


}   


}
```

Comment: Did you try it? Surely that's the simplest approach, and would have taken you less time than to ask the question. What would it even mean to return "one after another"?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? What did it return? And what compiler messages did you see? (hint: it tells you exactly what will happen)

Comment: Why downvote? I can imagine this person is confused.

Comment: Downvotes are probably because it shows a lack of having tried it, which would be a minimal condition for "research effort".

Comment: @L-Three Fixed that one as clearly not the point :-)

Comment: @L-Three it also won't build because there are no class declaration etc. This is not the point.

Comment: Turn the question around: what do you **want** to happen?

Comment: Make sure you're helping and not trolling.

Comment: My friends, i've just tried the code. in fact it returns a.

Comment: My friends, i've just tried the code. in fact it returns a. Thank you Endrju, i was really confused when i meet with this type of function in the code i am studying at the moment. As i thought me also, there must be some conditions statements for this to make sense but the programmer was writing a list of return statements without conditionning them which one to return. it is weird, so i thought that there may be something behind which i ignore and which i would not can discover alone without your help. but it seems nothing behind this. thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The first executed `return` statement in a sequence of instructions returns. So this will return `a`. You normally only see multiple return statements when there is some kind of condition which governs which one to return.

Comment: Thank you Joe,
yeah, it returns a. just i am studying some code source and each time the programmer was using this type of functions without conditionning which value to be returned. It seems for me weird to use a list of return statements and only the first one to be returned!!!
thank you anyway :)

Comment: Can you show us the actual code? If it is as you describe then there's probably something wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

`return b;` will never be executed in this scenario. Function execution will end on `return a;` and the value of `a` will be returned to calling code. Then program will continue from the point where it called this GetValue() function.

Other accuse you of not making enough research. I assume you are just not skilled enough to perform it. You can see what program is doing in various ways, e.g. by debugging it (setting a breakpoint and then stepping to see what's happening) or temporarily instrumenting the code with something that will let you know what's going on. For example:

```
Console.WriteLine('before return a');
return a;
Console.WriteLine('after return a, before return b');
return b;
```

Also do the same when calling the function. Get acquainted with these topics. And have fun with programming :-)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `return` statements only make sense if you have conditions in your method.

Example:

```
public static float GetValue() {
    if (a) {
        return x;
    }
    else {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are instances where multiple `return` statements can be valid in C#.  [thakrage's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23733120/3419534) of conditional returns is one.

Another would be where you actually want more than one number returned in a list. This can be achieved either by constructing the list in your method, adding the items, and then returning it, or else by more advanced techniques involving enumerable collections, like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<float> GetValues()
{
    // …
    yield return a;
    yield return b;
}
```

The usage would typically be in a loop, either explicitly like this:

```
foreach (float value in GetValues())
    // …
```

or implicitly by way of passing it to another method which operates on an enumerable collection:

```
float sumOfSquares = GetValues().Sum(f => f * f);
```

From your question I strongly doubt that this is what you wanted to know, but it's another instance where you might come across it in the future.